# How can I change the font size of the authors and the affiliation in Latex?

Tags: fontsize, titles

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article} % 11pt for all the article
\begin{document}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 16pt
\title{{\myfont MY TITLE}}%Title in 16pt
\author{MY NAME}% **I need it in 12pt**
\affil{University of...}% **I need it in 9pt**
```

How can the font sizes be changed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: `\font\myfont=cmr12 at 16pt` is a plain TeX command, use `\documentclass[16pt,...]{article}` instead (This will automatically load the correct Computer Modern family). To change the font size in title and author use the corresponding factor inside the argument, like `\title{\Huge The Title}`. Don't set any absolute fontsizes by yourself (e.g. `\font ... at 16pt`), always use the relative sizes (e.g. `\large`). BTW: `\affil` isn't defined by `article`.

Comment: @HenriMenke `\documentclass[16pt]{article}` wont do anything, the valid options are 10pt, 11pt and 12pt. With `extarticle` you have more options, including 14pt and 17pt.

Comment: Thanks Henri, but I need 11pt for all the document, I just need to change the size of the title (16pt), the authors (12pt) and the affiliation (9pt). They are instructions from a journal, I thing I can't use \large or \Huge.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right, of course. Please accept my apologies for not thinking before typing.

Comment: @damb This might be of interest for you: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text There is a table with absolute font sizes for the corresponding scaling commands, e.g. if your article uses `11pt`, then `\LARGE` will be at `15.84985pt`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I thing I can use this table, it is very useful

Comment: @HenriMenke, shouldn't you change your comment into an answer?  Adding size indicators such as `\Huge` inside the `\title{}` definition is the simplest method.

Comment: @Mars As OP wants to explicitly specify the fontsize, I don't think my comment is worth an answer.

Answer (score 20):

You can get the *exact* font sizes you need in a proper way; the idea is to use `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` and a scalable font allowing the desired sizes (`lmodern`, for example). `authblk` offers `\Authfont` and `\Afillfont` to customize font attributes for authors and affiliations; a simple patch to `\@maketitle` allows you to choose the exact desired font for the title:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE \@title}{\fontsize{16}{19.2}\selectfont\@title}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\itshape}

\title{MY TITLE} 
\author{MY NAME}
\affil{University of..}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using the @Henrimenke recommendation, you can find it [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article} % 11pt for all the article
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\begin{document}
\title{\LARGE MY TITLE}          %Title in 16pt=15.84985
\author{\large MY NAME}            % I need it in 12pt=11.74988
\affil{\footnotesize University of..}   % I need it in 9pt=9.24994
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal of changing the title size can also be addressed using the `titling` package:

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily}
\posttitle{\end{flushleft}}
```