# How can I change the font size of the title and the font size of the authors in Latex?

Tags: fontsize, titles

I need a font size of 16pt for the title and 12pt for the authors. I'm writing an article class document in 11pt:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
```

Comment: Looks like this is linked to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128043/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-the-authors-and-the-affiliation-in-latex: the 'answer' from alexsh looks suspiciously like that question (with the plain TeX stuff, _etc._)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will let you put whatever font you desire in the title: (just replace `\myfont`)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 40pt
\title{{\myfont Who knows}}
\author{{\Huge A.~U.~Thor}}
\maketitle
Paper.
\end{document}
```

You can also use \Large or \Huge instead of \myfont, to fit the rest of the document style (this way LaTeX will only change the size of the font)

Comment: Thank you alexsh, it worked. The title is fine now. I just need change the size font of the authors.

Comment: I added the one for the author, essentially the same thing, you can also make other choices for the font, just like you can for the title. If you are interested in different fonts available for TeX/LaTeX, check out the font catalog at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html. If this answer works, please mark it as acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment above and in many other questions on this site, it is a bad practice to add formatting markup in `\title`, `\author` or any command that has a semantics meaning (including sectioning commands).

Instead to the `titlesec` or `titling` packages (that are the "standard" answer),
I would suggest to load the `etoolbox` package and use its `\patchcmd` command like this (for the title, the printing in performed by `\@maketitle`):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\Huge}{\typeout{OK 1}}{\typeout{Failed 1}}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\large \lineskip}{\Large \lineskip}{\typeout{OK 2}}{\typeout{Failed 2}}
\makeatother

\title{A simple example of \textbackslash Huge title}
\author{Nice and \textbackslash Large author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

yieding :
[image]

in place of

[image]

In order to know which replacement (here `\LARGE` and `\large \lineskip`) one has to perform, look at the definition of the command, by using :

- Either the `\meaning` or the `\show` commands printing command definition in the pdf and in the terminal respectively.
- Or similarly, for protected commands, the `\ShowCommand` (LaTeX2e fall 2020) or `\showcmd` (package `show2e`).
- Or, on the command line, `texdef -t latex -c article -F @maketitle`.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, download the template and remplace the command `\title{Resumé title}`
 in the template by the two following lines: `\font\myfont=cmr12 at 15pt` and `\title{{\myfont I am the title}}` and your problem is solved.....

Comment: This might work, but it is really bad practice and bad advice. Why using TeX commands in a LaTeX document? On the other hand, the other answer gives exactly the same bad advice.

Comment: What is a good piece of advice then?

Comment: @Johannes_B How would you do it then?

Comment: @carl Probably like that https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595261/37907

Comment: Or look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907