# Font size of title

Tags: fontsize, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\documentclass[16pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\title{\textbf{Research Statement}}
\author{Xxx Yyyy}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\large

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

If you compile that code you will produce the picture below.
I have a few questions. How can I change the font size of the title and author? Also, how can I make "1.Introduction" slightly larger than the text "Bla Bla Bla"?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128153/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-the-title-and-the-font-size-of-the-authors-in it might answer your question

Comment: @PaulA, I dont think so. The documentclass in my file and in the link which you've provided are different.

Comment: you have `\large` here increasing the size of the text while leaving the title and section headings, don't use size changes for the. whole document, this is making all the headings look wrong sized.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use more or less the standard amsart commands but just modify the sizes it uses in the title and section headings, you could try patching the commands in question with something like this:

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% change title size
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\normalsize}{\LARGE}{}{}
% change author size
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\MakeUppercase {\authors }}{\MakeUppercase{\Large\authors}}{}{}
% change section title size
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\Large}{}{}
\makeatother
```

(Change `\LARGE`/`\Large` to whatever sizing command you'd prefer: `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\Huge`, etc.)

[image: example output]

You could also consider loading package such as [titling](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling?lang=en) and [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en), which provide more fine grained control over these kinds of things.

You could also considering using a different document class. `amsart` makes sense if you are writing for an AMS journal. If you are, you should keep their defaults. If you aren't, then you're free to use one of many other alternatives.

Comment: It completely answers my question! But I am just writing research statement so I don't know is `amsmart` is fine for that

Comment: Depends who the research statement is for, I suppose... but I usually try to stick to the "standard" document classes (article, report, book, etc.) unless I've been provided a custom one by the journal, or institution or funding agency, etc.

Comment: @frabjous -- If a document is really math-heavy, with a lot of theorems and display material, then `amsart` provides features that aren't present in the basic classes.  One reason for its more "sober" design (besides tradition) is that the basic classes are felt by the designers to be examples of the "National Enquirer" style.  However, the construction of these classes was designed to be, as much as possible, compatible with the basic classes so that a manuscript prepared using a basic class could be easily "dropped into" an AMS class.  Your patches are the best way to go.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I see why you'd want the ams packages like amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, etc., in a math-heavy document, but not why you'd want to use their document classes like amsart, unless you were targetting one of the journals that use it. Is there something in particular you had in mind that makes them attractive outside that context? (You mentioned the style, but OP clearly isn't happy with the style and wants to change it.)

Comment: @frabjous -- Mathematicians who submit work to the AMS get used to those classes and use them for other purposes as well.  I don't know if the OP here is such a person.  It's merely stated that `amsart` is being used.