# How to change font-size of title text using \makeatletter

Tags: titles, fontsize

I tried to change the size of my title, and found this: [How can I change the font size of the authors and the affiliation in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128043/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-the-authors-and-the-affiliation-in-latex), but I was unable to do it because an error message kept popping up that said:

```
No \title given. [...{\fontsize{40pt}{49.2pt}\selectfont\@title]
```

Any help would be welcome!

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
{\LARGE \@title}{\fontsize{40pt}{49.2pt}\selectfont\@title}{}{}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newcommand\tikztextbf[1]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikztitle]
    \node [text=white] {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
  \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [text=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (textnode) {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
      \shade[path fading=tikztitle,fit fading=false,left color=green,right color=black]
      (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}
  \textbf{\usebox\tempbox{}}%
}

\title{\tikztextbf{The logic of tautologies!!}} 
\author{D.R.}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add `\end{document}` to your code, it compiles without error. You need to make sure the example produces the problem you are reporting.

Comment: What does this have to do with `\makeletter`?

Comment: It now has the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That attempts to typeset stuff before `\begin{document}` which is obviously going to end in tears ;).

Comment: How do I typeset after \begin{document}? Do I copy and paste the title formatting stuff after the \begin{document}? Sorry if this question is silly, I'm kind of new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
\normalfont \Large \bfseries
```

to

```
\fontsize{40pt}{49.2pt}\selectfont
```

or whatever you wish it to be.

```
{\LARGE \@title}{\fontsize{40pt}{49.2pt}\selectfont\@title}{}{}
```

This tells LaTeX to do the following:

1. Switch to `\LARGE`.
2. Typeset the title.
3. Switch to 40pt font with 49.2pt baseline skip.
4. Typeset the title again.

Moreover, you are telling LaTeX to do this before:

1. `\begin{document}`;
2. specifying a title.

Try to see it from LaTeX's perspective: what can it do but complain?